# WSO2 ESB more than 10 JMS Queue not working

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

While develping WSO2 flows with proxies and queues we discovered that with more than 10 queues in the ActiveMQ, some proxy do not get the messages from the JMS anymore.

We found follwing links on this problem, but the correct solution can't be found:

http://node2.wso2.org/forum/thread/9516

Where do I have to put the mentioned parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could be found here:
http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/06/wso2-esb-example-processing-long-message-backlog

You have to add the following parameters to your start script of the WSO2

```
wso2server.bat -Dsnd_t_max=600 -Dsnd_t_core=120
```